# Fastlane command not found Mac OS Catalina

Tags: rubygems, fastlane

Hi I've searched all links here on stackoverflow but my issue is still not resolved.

I have ruby from homebrew `brew install ruby`

then added this to PATH

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

then I've added .gems as $GEM_HOME

then I've install fastlane via `gem install fastlane -NV`

added this to ~/.zshrc

```
export PATH="$HOME/.fastlane/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.fastlane/bin/fastlane_lib:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.gems/bin/fastlane:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin/fastlane:$PATH"
```

but still I get `zsh: command not found: fastlane`

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It's working now. I just added these line to .zshrc

```
export GEM_HOME=~/.gems
export PATH="$HOME/.gems/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.fastlane/bin:$PATH"
```